# Converting NUMBER variable to Datetime stamp

Tags: oracle, to-timestamp

I am using the following, where I am converting NUMBER variable to Datetime stamp.

```
to_char(
 (to_timestamp('01-JAN-1970 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + 
 (END_SAMPLE_TS_5MIN_MS/(1000*60*60*24)),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

But I notice the output resulting from above is behind by 1 second from actual value.
Say for example if `END_SAMPLE_TS_5MIN_MS=1388984699999.`
Instead of showing : `06Jan2014 05:04:59`
It is showing it as `06Jan2014 05:05:00`
The milliseconds are rounded to nearest second.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use numtodsinterval, something like:

```
select to_timestamp('01-JAN-1970 00:00:00.000','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3')  +
    numtodsinterval(1388984699.999, 'SECOND')
    from dual;
```

Output:

```
1/6/2014 5:04:59.999000000 AM
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in utilizing the milliseconds to round up, you can effectively take the "floor" of your epoch with a substring:

`select to_char((to_timestamp('01-JAN-1970 00:00:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')+(substr(1388984699999,1,length(1388984699999)-3)/(60*60*24))),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
from dual`

We're really just taking the substring of our string minus the last 3 digits (milliseconds in this unix timestamp format) and then adding it to the epoch to get your time.